# Issue in joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I m facing an issue in my SQL Query
My query is

```
select * from Character,A where Character.id=A.id
```

I guess character is a reserve word which is creating problem. But dont have to rename this table name.
Please suggest

Comment: Also use an `INNER JOIN` instead of the cross join(old style join) which builds a cartesian product: `select A.*,C.* from Character C INNER JOIN A where C.id=A.id` (replace * which the column names)

Comment: the correct syntax will depend on the database you are using - what is that? MySQL? Oracle? please identify this to get the right answer

Comment: @Tim, A cartesian product with an appropriate where clause will be detected as an inner join by many good optimizers.

Comment: @WalterMitty: You're right. But once he modifies or forgets to add   the JOIN criteria in the WHERE clause it's turned  into a CROSS JOIN. It's less raeadable and more error-prone anyway.

Comment: I agree that the traditional syntax, as illustrated in the Q, is less readable and more error-prone than the explicit INNER JOIN syntax.  Still, this is a side issue.  The real problem is using a reserved word as a table name.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, `character` is a reserved word, although it is not a reserved word in other databases.  The list of MySQL reserved words is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html).  You use backticks to escape values in MySQL.

You should also use proper, explicit `join` syntax:

```
select *
from `Character` c join
     A 
     on c.id = A.id;
```

A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: What if we use "," ??

Comment: avoid using double quotes, the correct markup is backticks which don't appear to be showing in this answer, regrettably SO's editor als uses backticks so please just ignore spaces in the the following:  ` Character ` (without spaces)

Comment: @VishalSrivastava . . . Brilliant.  I said what to do and then I didn't follow my own advice.  The answer has been fixed.  If you use commas in the `from` clause, just replace them with `cross join`.

Answer (score 0):

note the use of backticks

```
select *
from `Character`
inner join A 
     on `Character`.id = A.id
;
```